# Android not sizing Custom Dialog big enough

Tags: android, dialog

I am using a custom Dialog that contains a text field, an image, and a button. The text can contain HTML. Sometimes the bottom of the dialog gets chopped off the bottom when the text is long enough. How can I prevent this? I want Android to determine the size of the dialog but it doesn't seem to be doing that. DO I need to size the Dialog myself in this case?

Here is the layout...

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/alert_root_incorrect"
  style="@style/AlertDialogTheme"
  android:background="@drawable/rounded_alert"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
>
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_alert"
  >

    <TableLayout
      android:stretchColumns="0"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

      <TableRow>
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="left"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:text="Sorry, that's wrong!"
          android:textColor="@color/gray_dark" />

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/check"
          android:background="@drawable/xmark"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

      </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/alert_text"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="none"
      android:text="In fact, this is where the explanation will go. Something about how this passage related to the topic"
      android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/okay_button"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="@drawable/rounded_alert_button"
      android:text="Okay"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="20sp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code I am using to load it...

```
if ( null == layout ) {
   this.layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_incorrect, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.alert_root_incorrect));
}

TextView message = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.alert_text);
message.setText(Html.fromHtml(card.getConclusion()));
((Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.okay_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      dismissDialog(INCORRECT_DIALOG);
      nextQuestion();
   }
});

layout.requestLayout();

dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
dialog.setContentView(layout);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

return dialog;
```

And here's a snap of what I mean..

[image]

Thanks,

John

Comment: It may be that the `style` you selected has some size constraints in it, which is preventing your dialog from sizing.  Try without a style and see if there's a difference.  A `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` is easier than `TableLayout`, and why are there two nested `LinearLayout`s you only need one. Eliminate "extra" views like that where possible, they can interfere with layout.  I've also had trouble sizing `Button`s when also setting the `textSize`.  You can try removing padding from the `Button`.  If your background is a 9-patch, there may also be issues with margin settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect but I've corrected it by setting the layout of the dialog relative to the default display.

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
dialog.setContentView(layout);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(
    (int)(window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()  * .90),
    (int)(window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() * .90 ));

dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Just tweak the ".90" values until it feels right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. You should add a Linearlayout at the outside of your dialog's xml file
2. Then set this Linearlayout's gravity as "center"
3. the last step is creating a LayoutParams and set it to the dialog

   android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams();
       lp.width = android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
       lp.height = android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
       alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);